# PHP-Module from Apache on Windows looses ability to read from local file system (include, require, fopen fail)

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-server-2019, php7

I'm running Apache2.4 with php7.4 module on a virtual Windows Server 2019 system. Regularely at 01:00 AM the php module looses the ability to read includes, requires or fopen streams from the local file system (C:) - after a restart of the Apache or a reboot of the virtual machine everything turns to be ok. Apache is installed as Service and runs on a user account with write/read permissions to all directories involved. The required files are all on the right place, have the right permissions and the include-path is correct - please remember that everything works fine after a reboot till 01:00 AM.

Log entry example in error.log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/apps/pi/move.php' (include_path='.;C:\\apps\\phplib') in Unknown on line 0
```

The only scheduled task running at 01:00 AM is the Ivanti DSM Installer.

Has anyone ever heard of the Ivanti DSM conflicting with Apache/php-module or can guess a logical connection between Installer and Apache/php? Maybe affecting the permission system on windows?

**Update:**

It seems the DSM installer is not guilty - after deactivating the services the problem still remains.

Strange thing that happens: the requests per second are decreasing and paradoxically the number of worker increases notably, see graphics:

[Apache-Status at 01:00 AM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGiBU.png)

Any hint is heavily appreciated!
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what the reason is, but I'll try to help you decide.
Try to take configs from XAMPP and compare them with yours.
When setting up Apache php this worked for me.
Also see what account Apache is running from.

Comment: Thank you for your hints - the only remarkable difference is that I use the log rotation module for apache, but the rotation happens at other times.